# How to use ODE45 to solve for a system of differential equations with a difficult end condition?

Tags: matlab, solver, ode45

My system of equations can be written down as-

> y1' = F_1(x,y1,y2)

> y2' = F_2(x,y1,y2)

where F1 and F2 are some functions of x, y1, y2. y1 and y2 are functions of x and y1'=dy1_dx and y2'=dy2_dx.

The initial condition is at x=0, y1=y2=0. However I need the solution at y1=1, i.e. as soon as y1=1 is reached, the iteration needs to stop. I want to solve it using a proper solver like ODE45 or ODE15s in MATLAB. However I am not sure how to set the x_span i.e. initial and final values of x. Please guide me.

Note that, setting x at a large value say 1000 will not help, because I don't know where y1=1.

Comment: this question seems a little odd, as the system of equations is undetermined. You have two differential equations, but three variables. Or is y1 and y2 functions of x and the system of equations you provided is resulting from a change of variables to reduce the order of the differential equation?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that y1 and y2 are indeed functions of x and y1'=dy1_dx and y2'=dy2_dx. I am updating the question.

Comment: could you provide the differential equation you are trying to solve? that  may be helpful to develop an answer for the question.

Comment: @Thales The functions F1 and F2 indicate the functions. I cannot write the equations because they are almost 35 lines each, but you can appehend them behind the functions F1 and F2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an event function (typically equal to y1-1) that you give to the ODE solver:
https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ode-event-location.html

As soon as the solver detect a sign change of your event function, it stops.